# How to connect to mysql UNIX server from java windows application using jdbc?

Tags: java

I am working on java windows application. I am trying to connect to mysql server(Localhost via UNIX socket) using jdbc. But it is displaying an error message as
 `"Access denied for user 'root'@'ipaddress'.`I didn't get what is the problem.Is it the problem connecting to unix server from jdbc? If so how can I resolve this issue.Please help me regarding this.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up mysql to allow remote connection for any users. The default syntax is:

grant  on  to @ identified by

eg
grant all on test.* to root@ipaddress identified by root

Will allow 'root' to connect from that IP using that password and give all permissions on all tables in that database.

Comment: hi i gave mydatabase name in place of test and executed the query but it is displaying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'root' at line 1"

Comment: Did you give your ipaddress value instead of ipaddress.eg: root@172.19.56.77 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Also, before testing your java app, try connecting using mysql workbench or another client. Only after it succeeds run the java app.